# Conflicting documentation for `[UIView initWithFrame:]`: nullable or nonnull?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, initwithframe, objective-c-nullability

Using `CLANG_ANALYZER_NONNULL` (i.e. `-Xclang nullability`), I got "*Null is returned from a function that is expected to return a non-null value*":

[image]

Using Xcode 7.3 and iOS 9.3 documentation, I checked `initWithFrame:` and it can return `nil`:

[image: description]

But UIView.h encapsulates everything with `NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN`, so we can interpret the following:

[image: interface]

as:

```
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
```

**So documentation explains it's `nullable`, while header file says it's `nonnull`. Which one to trust?**

Should I write:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (!self) {
        // workaround for clang analyzer
        return (void * _Nonnull)nil;
    }
    // Initialization code
    return self;
}
```

Or:

```
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    // Initialization code
    return self;
}
```

## UPDATE

Xcode documentation was updated and is now:
[image: initWithFrame: documentation]

So no more conflict.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "trust".  The compiler (and associated tooling) is going to "trust" the annotations, not the documentation.  If you want your code to pass without warning, and not give headaches to Swift users, assume the `nonnull` attribute is correct.

Comment: Facing a similar issue with `[NSURL URLWithString:]`, as declaration wants the string to be `nonnull`, but description states it can be `nil`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of `UIView`'s `-initWithFrame` initializer, the recommendation is to not defensively check the result of calling the super initializer because there is realistically nothing an application can do to recover from a failed `UIView` allocation.

Also, as of Xcode 7.3 beta 4, the static analyzer no longer warns here. It now doesn't warn about returning nil from the `-init`, `-copy`, and `-mutableCopy` families even when these methods have a return type with a `nonnull` type qualifier to avoid warning on exactly this common defensive idiom.

Comment: Hello Devin. Thank you for answering. I wasn't the one to downvote you, as I know you work for Apple since [you replied to me in the past](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=26143). I understand I should trust Apple's headers more, so I will remove defensive code for methods returning `nonnull instancetype`.

Comment: Does this come from official sources, or it's an observation based on latest XCode beta's static analyzer behaviour?

Comment: Devin, may you look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/34195149/1033581 as well? Or confirm that it is OK for [[AFURLSessionManager (nonnull instancetype)initWithSessionConfiguration:](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.m#L511)] to return `nil`?

Answer (score 1):

The headers usually take precedence, as many times the documentation is either left behind or overlooked. `UIKit` (among the other `CocoaTouch` frameworks) headers are more up-to-date than the documentation for another reason: better `Swift` interoperability.

So you should go with the second approach:

```
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    // Initialization code
    return self;
}
```

Returning `nonnull` from this initializer is also logical, as an `UIView` is an abstract object that holds information about something that will eventually be rendered on the screen, it doesn't have many restrictions on it own.

Similarly, it doesn't make much sense to pass a nil string to `[NSURL URLWithString:]` as `NSURL` strings have clearly defined requirements, and a `nil` one doesn't satisfy them, so it makes sense to have the `nonnull` annotation here.